# between two users messages conversation in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating simple private message conversation script. my script showing incoming users conversation. but messages which i sent to another user not showing. 
any one can help me i have lot of tried.

my database

```
id  from_id  from_name  to_id   to_name  msg
1   2        master     3       john     hi how are you?
2   3        john       2       master   fine
3   2        master     3       john     hi
```

Here is my code conversation

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['to_id'])) {
$from_id = $_GET['to_id'];  
}

if (isset($_GET['to_name'])) {
$from_name = $_GET['to_name'];  
}

if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
$to_id = $_SESSION['userid'];  
}

require_once"config.php";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from inbox where from_id=? and from_name=? and to_id=? ")){
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $from_id,$from_name,$to_id);
$stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>

<div class="msg">
<?php echo $row['from_name'];?>
<?php echo $row['msg'];?>
<?php 
}
}
?>
</div>
```

[output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3GFU.jpg)

Comment: What are the $from_id, $from_name and, $to_id values?

Comment: to_id value form users table userid

Comment: I can see that. What are the actual values? What is really coming in from the form and in the session. Do echo statements.

Comment: inserting values to other users from login user

Comment: hi i can solve your problem using core php..

Comment: can you help me plz

Comment: can you post your current output.

Comment: post screen shot of your output..  means the message which are printing

Comment: anothor user messages showing  but messages which i sent not showing

Comment: wait.. let me create a database. going to work on your problemm

Comment: can you send me your out put image..

Comment: I added image can you check plz

Comment: hi, can you tell me why you are using from_name in your query..

Comment: sorry i have added old image can you check now i have added new image

Comment: plz can you help me

Comment: bro, actually i am not familiar with prepared statement

Comment: i have solved your problem, soccessfully

Comment: can i put here the value instead of using here variable...
for eg
SELECT * from inbox where from_id=1 and from_name=jhon and to_id=3

Comment: bro ok can you checked

Comment: yeah, i have solved your problem

Comment: actually you have solved my problem. thank you very much brother. lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['to_id'])) {
$from_id1 = $_GET['to_id'];  
}

if (isset($_GET['to_name'])) {
$from_name1 = $_GET['to_name'];  
}

if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
$to_id1 = $_SESSION['userid'];  
}
require_once"config.php";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from inbox where (from_id='2' and to_id='3' and from_name ='jhon') || (from_id='3' and to_id='2')")){
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $from_id,$from_name,$to_id);
$stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>

<div class="msg">
<?php echo $row['from_name'];?>
<?php echo $row['msg'];?>
<?php 
}
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\npm\replay.php on line 50

Comment: like this messages

Comment: same results getting

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.